# Scheduled Task with Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job with parallelism 5 (for now !!). And one of the richFlatMap stream opens one file in the `open(Configuration parameters)` method. In the `flatMap`operation there is no any open action, it just read the file to search something. (There is a utility class which has a method like `utilityClass.searchText('abc')`). Here is the boilerplate code:

```java
public class MyFlatMap extends RichFlatMapFunction<...> {

    private MyUtilityFile myFile;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        myFile.Open("fileLocation");
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(...) throws Exception {
        String text = myFile.searchText('abc');
        if (text != null) // take an action
        else // another action
    }

}
```

This file is being updated by the python script every day at specific time. Therefore I should also open the newly created file (by python script) in the flatMap stream.

I just though that this can be done by `ScheduledExecutorService` with only one thread pool.

> I can not open this file every flatMap calls because it is big.

Here is the boilerplate code I am trying to write:

```java
public class MyFlatMap extends RichFlatMapFunction<...> implements Runnable {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    private MyUtilityFile myFile;

    @Override
    public void run() {
       myFile.Open("fileLocation");     
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 1, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);

        myFile.Open("fileLocation");
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(...) throws Exception {
        String text = myFile.searchText('abc');
        if (text != null) // take an action
        else // another action
    }

}
```

Is this boilerplate okey for Flink environment? If not, how can i open the file with a scheduled manner? (There is no option such as "after updating file send event with kafka and read event by flink")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can directly implement the ProcessingTimeCallback interface, which supports timer operations

```
public class MyFlatMap extends RichFlatMapFunction<...> implements ProcessingTimeCallback { 
    private MyUtilityFile myFile;

 
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 1, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);

        final long now = getProcessingTimeService().getCurrentProcessingTime();
        getProcessingTimeService().registerTimer(now + 3600000, this);

        myFile.Open("fileLocation");
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(...) throws Exception {
        String text = myFile.searchText('abc');
        if (text != null) // take an action
        else // another action
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessingTime(long timestamp) throws Exception {
        myFile.Open("fileLocation");

        final long now = getProcessingTimeService().getCurrentProcessingTime();
        getProcessingTimeService().registerTimer(now + 3600000, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank your for you response, but i could not find  getProcessingTimeService() method. Which package should i import ?

Comment: ((StreamingRuntimeContext) getRuntimeContext()).getProcessingTimeService() in open function

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected with processingTimeService. I am looking a solution like this