# Run a scheduled task in a Apache Flink function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a `RichAsyncFunction` and wish to run a scheduled task within it. I'm trying to use `ProcessingTimeService.ProcessingTimeCallback` but the `TimeService` object cannot be retrieved from the`RichAsyncFunction` runtime context.

```
public class MyFunction extends RichAsyncFunction<..> implements ProcessingTimeService.ProcessingTimeCallback {
  @Override
  public void open(Configuration configuration) {
    val timeService = ((StreamingRuntimeContext) getRuntimeContext()).getProcessingTimeService(); 
  }

}
```

The code line `((StreamingRuntimeContext) getRuntimeContext()).getProcessingTimeService()` throws a ClassCastException with error `RichAsyncFunction$RichAsyncFunctionRuntimeContext cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamingRuntimeContext`

I got the idea to use `ProcessingTimeCallback` from this [Scheduled Task with Apache Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584810/scheduled-task-with-apache-flink) thread but cannot get it to work on the RichAsyncFunction. Wondering how to implement the callback or what approach to use to run the scheduled task.

I've tried to schedule the task with `ScheduledExecutorService` but it causes some thread-starvation issues (not the focus of this qtn)

Running Flink v1.15.2

Comment: What does the scheduled task do? Why should it be in an Async Function?

Comment: The scheduled task periodically fetches an auth token used by a http client that's asynchronously invoked in the RichAsyncFunction

Answer (score 1):

If you have some regularly scheduled "task" that you want to do inside of the Flink runtime for some reason, then a typical way to handle this is with a custom source that generates a regularly scheduled event, and an operator that triggers of that event to perform the task.

Separately, timers are saved in keyed state, so they're only available in keyed functions.